# How can I run a function when a radio is selected and I click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created this simple code that I'll use to store in the user's browser, so, I'd like to know how can I run a function when there's a selected radio and when I click the delete button, using JS or JQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

check it on [liveweave](http://liveweave.com/gBlAMb)

P.S.: Your browser should have [WebStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) support

```js
var taskCounter = 1 + Number(localStorage.getItem("count"));
var name = "de"+ taskCounter;

for(var i=1;i<taskCounter;i++){
  var temp = "de" + i;
  document.writeln("<br/>"+'<input type="radio"  name="rad" value="'+localStorage.getItem(temp)+'" /> <label>'+localStorage.getItem(temp)+'</lable>');
}

function saveItUp(){
      var desc = $('#descrip').val();
      alert(desc);
      // Store
      localStorage.setItem(name, desc);
      localStorage.setItem("count", taskCounter);
      // Retrieve
      console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));
      console.log(localStorage.getItem("count"));
}

//This is where I'm trying to do that, I know selected doesn't exist, but I put it just for a better comprehension
function deleteItUp(){
  $('input:radio').selected(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      alert(this.value);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      
      <label>Task</label> <textarea id="descrip"></textarea>
      
      <button onclick="saveItUp();" id="save">Save it</button>
      <button onclick="deleteItUp();" id="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but, I never said checkbox, It has (generates) radios when you save something

Comment: I don't see the radio...

Comment: @DZanella try the link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying other ways to achieve it, and I found a nice way that gave me the expected result, thank all of you who tried to help me.

```js
var taskCounter = 1 + Number(localStorage.getItem("count"));
var name = "de" + taskCounter;

for (var i = 1; i < taskCounter; i++) {
  var temp = "de" + i;
  document.writeln("<br/>" + '<input type="radio"  name="rad" value="' + temp + '" /> <label>' + 'Code: ' + temp + ' | Value: ' + localStorage.getItem(temp) + '</lable>');
}

function saveItUp() {
  var desc = $('#descrip').val();
  alert(desc);
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem(name, desc);
  localStorage.setItem("count", taskCounter);
  // Retrieve
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("count"));
}


var selectedRadioId = 0;

$('input:radio').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    selectedRadioId = this.value;
  }
});

function deleteItUp() {
  if (selectedRadioId !== 0) {
    alert('Deleting!');
  } else {
    alert("Radio hasn't been checked!");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

    <label>Task</label>
    <textarea id="descrip"></textarea>

    <button onclick="saveItUp();" id="save">Save it</button>
    <button onclick="deleteItUp();" id="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have edited your snippet. Use `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')` to see whether the radio button is checked. You will need to modify the selector to get the appropriate radio button if there are multiple on the page.

```js
var taskCounter = 1 + Number(localStorage.getItem("count"));
var name = "de" + taskCounter;

for (var i = 1; i < taskCounter; i++) {
  var temp = "de" + i;
  document.writeln("<br/>" + '<input type="radio"  name="rad" value="' + localStorage.getItem(temp) + '" /> <label>' + localStorage.getItem(temp) + '</lable>');
}

function saveItUp() {
  var desc = $('#descrip').val();
  alert(desc);
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem(name, desc);
  localStorage.setItem("count", taskCounter);
  // Retrieve
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(name));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("count"));
}

//This is where I'm trying to do that, I know selected doesn't exist, but I put it just for a better comprehension
function deleteItUp() {
  if ($('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')) {
    alert('Deleting!');
  } else {
    alert('Delete radio not checked!');
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">

    <label>Task</label>
    <textarea id="descrip"></textarea>
    
    <button onclick="saveItUp();" id="save">Save it</button>
    <button onclick="deleteItUp();" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <input type="radio">Check to delete
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about firing an event when a radio button is checked and then calling a callback function: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/